# Windows crashes after sleep

Tags: windows-8.1

I did clean install of W8.1 PRO (original). I haven't installed anything else, just booted it and closed my laptop lid (closing lid should sleep computer). After opening it up, computer was shutdown. So I started computer with a power button, windows loaded and I got windows error message (I dunno how to get text from .tmp files).

What I tried: change settings what closing lid does: from sleep to shutdown and viceversa.

Comment: What did the error message say? Are you using Windows 8.1 certified drivers?

Comment: Go get and install the latest (Windows 8) drivers from the notebook's manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should try re-installing the drivers. Try re-installing Windows itself, do not install 8.1, there are many bugs to this new operating system. I'd say go with your previous operating system. Windows 7 or Vista. If your laptop came with 8.1 then install a ISO to a USB and install Win 7 or Vista.

---

If this doesn't help then you should go to STAPLES or your local electronics shop to get the button fixed.

---

Another Option : Method 2:
I would suggest you to run the Power troubleshooter to adjust your computer's power settings, and check if it works properly.
Open the Power troubleshooter
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-the-Power-troubleshooter

---

Taken all from this website : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/why-does-windows-crash-everytime-i-close-my-laptop/de64402b-c653-408a-a24d-98157629aad8

Comment: It works after I reinstalled external video card drivers. Dunno why it was broken..

Comment: Glad to have helped.